# Simplification of delta mutual information formula

Tags: optimization, mutual-information, bayesian-optimization

I'm calculating the difference between two mutual information's, to see if adding a new parameter is worth. My goal is to simplify the formula which might be a little CPU intensive, but I can't see any trivial way to do it. I'm working with discrete variables.

Suppose I have:

*{P1,P2}* inferring *F*. With mutual information *MI1 = I({P1,P2};F)*.

And want to see if it's worth adding *P3* (combined with *P1* and *P2*) to infer *F*. By now, i'm doing it naively by calculating *MI1* and then calculating *MI2 = I({P1,P2,P3};F)*. And I need this *DeltaMI = MI2 - MI1* to see if it's worth.

The problem is that this might be a little costly because two mutual information's are being computed instead of one. Is there any simplification of this *DeltaMI* calculation? If so, how can I do it?

PS: For mutual information between X and Y i'm using this formula:
[image]

Comment: You could use the chain rule for mutual information, which would say: I({P1,P2,P3}; F) = I({P1,P2};F) + I(P3;F|{P1, P2}), or delta = I(P3;F|{P1, P2}). However, calculating the conditional mutual information is usually not much easier than calculating the two MIs.

Comment: @GregVerSteeg Sir this is what i was looking for, I've implemented and made a couple of tests and you are right, indeed just 3% faster processing times. You can provide this as an answer if you want and I'll give it correct. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the chain rule for mutual information, which would say: $I({P1,P2,P3}; F) = I({P1,P2};F) + I(P3;F|{P1, P2})$, or $\delta = I(P3;F|{P1, P2})$. However, calculating the conditional mutual information is usually not much easier than calculating the two MIs.

Sometimes, a dedicated estimator of conditional mutual information can be more *accurate* than a taking the difference of two mutual information estimators which in general have different biases. A similar issue is discussed in the context of difference of entropy estimators in [Kraskov's famous paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0305641.pdf). Mutual information and conditional mutual information can be written as KL divergences, so direct KL estimators might work well, like [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d9dd/35cdebccec93a65cbd9044f3bc744f850c3b.pdf), but I can't point you to a good implementation explicitly for CMI. The one in [NPEET](https://github.com/gregversteeg/NPEET) is really just taking a difference of mutual information estimates.